# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a listbox ´cause I need to display some variables behavior, each item contain a simple chart and a title with the variable´s name. Any time I need to import new variables I read a cvs file with the variables values and fill a Variables Collection in my viewmodel. This Variable Collection is bound to the listbox. So, if I load two or three variables from this file the first time it work fine. The problem emerge when I try to load this file again and I add e bigest number of variables to my proyect.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection

This is my code (the exception happen at the line Variables.Collection.Add(...)):

```
private void ImportNewVariables(VariableDetailsViewModel[] variablesToImport, Worksheet worksheet)
        {
            ...
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() => Variables.Collection.Clear()));
            foreach (var variable in variablesToImport)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                (Action)(() => Variables.Collection.Add(variable)));
            }
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() => Variables.Selected = variablesToImport.FirstOrDefault(v => v.IsIncluded)));
            OnPropertyChanged("Variables");
        }
```

I guess the problem may be the listbox hasn´t modified its length and it try to evaluate the new item´s collection and then the resulting index gets out of range. I really don´t know why it work fine the first time and give an exception the next one.

Comment: It would really help if you post the `StackTrace` of the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Why do you need the `Dispatcher` here? Are you calling this method on a background thread?